# siunitx decimals only for numbers below 1

Tags: siunitx, number

Suppose I have the following table

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{S[table-alignment=right, 
                  round-mode=places, 
                  round-precision=1, 
                  table-format=5.3,
                  zero-decimal-to-integer]}
{title}  \\
11111    \\
11.11    \\
0.11     \\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

and I would like to round the numbers such that numbers above 1 are rounded to integers and numbers below 1 are rounded to first decimal. The result here would be `11111, 11, 0.1`.

I have tried the following combinations, which yielded undesirable results

```
round-mode=figures and round-precision=1: 10000, 10, 0.1
round-mode=figures and round-precision=5: 11111, 11.110, 0.11000
round-mode=places  and round-precision=1: 11111, 11.1, 0.1
```

but I cannot figure out the right settings to get what I need (and hope to be common enough that it is possible in `siunitx`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If this is only for use in tables then you can use `pgfplotstable` and preprocess the numbers.  Below I define a new key `round int` which provides the preprocessing.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{siunitx,pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}

\begin{document}

\makeatletter
\pgfplotsset{table/round int/.style={%
  /pgfplots/table/preproc cell content/.append code={%
    \pgfkeysgetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}\pgfmathresult
    \ifx\pgfmathresult\pgfutil@empty
    \else
    \pgfmathparse{abs(\pgfmathresult) > 1 ? round(\pgfmathresult) : \pgfmathresult}%
    \pgfkeyslet{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}\pgfmathresult
    \fi}}}
    \makeatother

\pgfplotstabletypeset[multicolumn names,
  columns/0/.style={column name={title},
    string type,
    column type={S[table-alignment=right,
                  round-mode=places,
                  round-precision=1,
                  table-format=-5.1,
                  zero-decimal-to-integer]},
    round int
}
  ]{
11111
11.11
11.85
0.11
0.19
-10.2
-10.8
}

\end{document}
```

Unfortunately the standard `preproc/expr` included with `pgfplotstable` has some settings that are not appropriate for your data.  The above code is based on how `preproc/expr` is implemented in that package.

If you want the numbers right-aligned in the column, just replace the `table-format` argument to the `S` column with `table-parse-only`:

[image: Right aligned sample]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{siunitx,pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}

\begin{document}

\makeatletter
\pgfplotsset{table/round int/.style={%
  /pgfplots/table/preproc cell content/.append code={%
    \pgfkeysgetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}\pgfmathresult
    \ifx\pgfmathresult\pgfutil@empty
    \else
    \pgfmathparse{abs(\pgfmathresult) > 1 ? round(\pgfmathresult) : \pgfmathresult}%
    \pgfkeyslet{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}\pgfmathresult
    \fi}}}
    \makeatother

\pgfplotstabletypeset[multicolumn names,
  columns/0/.style={column name={title},
    string type,
    column type={S[table-alignment=right,
                  round-mode=places,
                  round-precision=1,
                  zero-decimal-to-integer,
                  table-parse-only]},
    round int
}
  ]{
11111
11.11
11.85
0.11
0.19
-10.2
-10.8
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Interesting package! Is there a way of making all values right-aligned, such that the 1 in `0.1` is below the 2 in `12`?

Comment: @bumblebee Do want all numbers aligned to the right in the column, regardless of whether they are decimals or not?

Comment: @bumblebee Such an example now added.

Answer (score 4):

If you need to be able to use such a feature both in a table and outside in the text, you can make use of the math features in `pgfmath` to define the `\MyRoundMacro`:

```
\newcommand*{\MyRound}[1]{%
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\@IntegerComponent}{abs(#1)}%
    \ifnum\@IntegerComponent=0
        \num[round-mode=places, round-precision=1]{#1}%
    \else
        \num{\@IntegerComponent}%
    \fi
}%
```

You can either use this directly for *each* entry in the table or use the `collcell` package to define a custom column type `R` and use that:

```
\newcolumntype{R}{>{\collectcell\MyRound}r<{\endcollectcell}}
```

where the `r` is the desired column alignment.

The tables produced by the MWE below are as desired:

[image]

### Notes:

- Using the `R` column type requires that you wrap *any* not numerical content (such as the title lines) within a  `\multicolumn{1}{c}{}`.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{collcell}% Needed only if desire to use the `R` column type defined below
\usepackage{pgfmath}

\begin{document}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\MyRound}[1]{%
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\@IntegerComponent}{abs(#1)}%
    \ifnum\@IntegerComponent=0
        \num[round-mode=places, round-precision=1]{#1}%
    \else
        \num{\@IntegerComponent}%
    \fi
}%
\makeatother

\newcolumntype{R}{>{\collectcell\MyRound}r<{\endcollectcell}}

In a table the \verb|R| column type (requires non data entries to be wrapped in a \verb|\multicolumn|):

\begin{tabular}{R}
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{\bfseries title}  \\
    11111    \\
    11.11    \\
    0.11     \\
\end{tabular}

Can use the \verb|\MyRound| macro directly in a table and
outside of a table:

\begin{tabular}{r}
    {\bfseries title}  \\
    \MyRound{11111}    \\
    \MyRound{11.11}    \\
    \MyRound{0.11}     \\
\end{tabular}

Outside of a table:

\MyRound{11111}\par
\MyRound{11.11}\par
\MyRound{0.11}\par

\end{document}
```

Comment: This looks interesting, too. The in-table solution looks simple enough that it doesn't interfer with other table settings. However, the `0.11` (and all numbers smaller than 1) should be rounded to the first decimal.

Comment: @bumblebee: Have updated the answer to apply the appropriate options to `\num{}` so that `0.11` is displayed as `0.1`.